# Правильное название мероприятия

Tags: грамотность

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой из вариантов названия мероприятия будет более грамотным?

1. I-й Слет Московских вожатых.
2. I Слет Московских вожатых.
3. I Слет московских вожатых.
4. Первый слет московских вожатых.
5. Первый Слет Московских Вожатых.

Answer (score 3):

В любом случае употребление римской цифры неоправданно, а *-ый* неправильно. Выбирайте между *Первый* и *1-й*. И прописных букв внутри не должно быть. *1-й слет московских вожатых* – просто, правильно и без затей.

Comment: Почему ж неоправданно? Оправдано правилом:Римскими цифрами принято обозначать: •   Важные события: II мировая война, XIX Зимние Олимпийские игры.
  •   Номер века : VI век, XX век.
  •   Номер тысячелетия: I тысячелетие до н. э.
  •   Порядковый номер монарха: Генрих VII, Александр III, Петр I.
  •   Пункты списка: IV постулат Евклида, II закон термодинамики.
  •   Номера томов многотомных книг, номера частей, глав и разделов книг.
  •   Валентность химических элементов.
  •   Разметку циферблатов часов.
  •   Порядковый номер ступени в звукоряде.

Comment: Я же не сказал, что это грубая ошибка. Но согласитесь, что 1-й слет вожатых - это далеко не XX съезд КПСС. )))

II закон термодинамики НИ РАЗУ в книгах не встречал. Только 2-й. "V постулат Евклида" изредка попадался, хотя чаще пишут по-рабоче-крестьянски "5-й постулат"

Answer (score 1):

Корректны варианты:

1. 1-й слет московских вожатых.
2. Первый слет московских вожатых. (Если это официальное название слёта, если неофициальное, то возможно и с маленькой, строчной буквы: 24-26 сентября на территории ГОУ ДООЦ «Команда» прошёл первый городской туристско-краеведческий слёт вожатых города Москвы.)
3. I слет московских вожатых.

Вот сообщения Департамента культуры:

VI слёт вожатых педагогических отрядов ЮФО...

С 22 по 24 ноября на подмосковной базе «Спасатель» прошел Первый выездной слет педагогических отрядов Москвы.